# Set Login Display

Tags: system-installation, graphics, login, display

I'm using a x86 machine with integrated graphic and HDMI out and I can not disable the integrated graphics in the bios. I can disable the display when logged into a user account. However, on boot, the login is being display on the integrated graphics adapter and I can only see the mouse being shown.

How can I set which display login is being shown?